# Add image depending on value in query string

Tags: html, jquery

I have a landing page which will contain around 50 logos but I only want to display one logo depending on what the value is within the query string.

For example, if the query string contains 'LenderName="Platform"' then I'd like to show the platform logo.

I currently have this working by using 50 if statements. An Example below

```
$(window).on('load', function () {      
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Platform") > -1) {
        $('.qs-logo-container').html('<img src="../common/img/lenders/Platform.jpg" />');
      }
});
```

This does the job but I've noticed the image is slow to load in. They're only 5KB.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result with the image loading faster? I did consider including them within the HTML and using show or hide depending on the query string.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Off topic: 50 `if` statements, is not a good way to go.   Instead use [an existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+get+url+parameter) to get the url parameter value for `LenderName` then build your image path to match the lender name, either directly or via an array if the image names don't match the lender names exactly (and you can't rename the images).

Comment: Thanks, @freedomn-m for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the picture name matches the lender name you can do something like this

```
let lender = /* platform */;
if (window.location.href.indexOf(lender) > -1) {

//use backticks ` `
        $('.qs-logo-container').html(`<img src="../common/img/lenders/${lender}.jpg" />`);
      }
});
```